# problem deploying symfony app , error deploying symfony app , ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'filemtime(): stat failed for

Tags: symfony, error-handling, web-deployment, classnotfound, filetime

Im trynig to deploy my symfony app on a web server with the hoster alwaysdata.
My site works fine on localhost with wamp server , but after transferring all files on filezilla.

what I have done :

APP_ENV=prod

I run
composer update
composer dumpautoload

Im using symfony 4.4 and php 7.4.9 , my hoster alwaysdata works with php 7.4.9

But Im getting this error :

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adsgc.png)

any ideas to help me please ?

Comment: This looks like your site is still in dev. A prod website would have a way more generic error with no stack trace.

Comment: Also, your site is still trying to access `c:\wamp64` I don't know if you harcoded this path somewhere. First, try to manually delete the content of your `var/cache` folder

Comment: Ok thank you I fix it but now I get this error : Attempted to load interface "ServerInfoAwareConnection" from namespace "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Answer (score 0):

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError:
Attempted to load interface "ServerInfoAwareConnection" from namespace "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

  at /home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/Middleware/AbstractConnectionMiddleware.php:17
  at include()
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:571)
  at Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/composer/../doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/Middleware/AbstractConnectionMiddleware.php')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:428)
  at Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\Middleware\\AbstractConnectionMiddleware')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/error-handler/DebugClassLoader.php:353)
  at Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader->loadClass('Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\Middleware\\AbstractConnectionMiddleware')
  at spl_autoload_call('Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\Middleware\\AbstractConnectionMiddleware')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Logging/Connection.php:13)
  at include('/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Logging/Connection.php')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:571)
  at Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/composer/../doctrine/dbal/src/Logging/Connection.php')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:428)
  at Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Doctrine\\DBAL\\Logging\\Connection')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/error-handler/DebugClassLoader.php:353)
  at Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader->loadClass('Doctrine\\DBAL\\Logging\\Connection')
  at spl_autoload_call('Doctrine\\DBAL\\Logging\\Connection')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Logging/Driver.php:33)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\Driver->connect(array('url' => 'mysql://271447_test:Sitevoyages2sitevoyages2$@mysql-sitevoyages2.alwaysdata.net:3308/sitevoyages2_db?serverVersion=10.6.7&charset=utf8mb4', 'driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'host' => 'mysql-sitevoyages2.alwaysdata.net', 'port' => 3308, 'user' => '271447_test', 'password' => 'Sitevoyages2sitevoyages2$', 'driverOptions' => array(), 'serverVersion' => '10.6.7', 'defaultTableOptions' => array(), 'dbname' => 'sitevoyages2_db', 'charset' => 'utf8mb4'))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php:341)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php:1531)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getWrappedConnection()
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php:1029)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = \'BASE TABLE\'', array(), array())
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php:849)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->fetchAllAssociative('SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = \'BASE TABLE\'')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php:269)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager->listTableNames()
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Schema/AbstractSchemaManager.php:255)
  at Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager->tablesExist(array('doctrine_migration_versions'))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Metadata/Storage/TableMetadataStorage.php:195)
  at Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\Storage\TableMetadataStorage->isInitialized()
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Metadata/Storage/TableMetadataStorage.php:77)
  at Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\Storage\TableMetadataStorage->getExecutedMigrations()
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle/Collector/MigrationsCollector.php:37)
  at Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\Collector\MigrationsCollector->collect(object(Request), object(Response), object(ClassNotFoundError))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/Profiler.php:178)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler->collect(object(Request), object(Response), object(ClassNotFoundError))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/ProfilerListener.php:90)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener->onKernelResponse(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:126)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:264)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.response', object(ResponseEvent))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:239)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.response', object(ResponseEvent))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:168)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:191)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse(object(Response), object(Request), 2)
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:179)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 2)
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:80)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 2, false)
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/ErrorListener.php:60)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorListener->onKernelException(object(ExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exception', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:126)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(ExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exception', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:264)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.exception', object(ExceptionEvent))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:239)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.exception', object(ExceptionEvent))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(object(ExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exception')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:168)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch(object(ExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exception')
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:219)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleThrowable(object(ClassNotFoundError), object(Request), 1)
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:112)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminateWithException(object(ClassNotFoundError), object(Request))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/DebugHandlersListener.php:129)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\{closure}(object(ClassNotFoundError))
     (/home/sitevoyages2/www/mesvoyages2/vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorHandler.php:601)
  at Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler->handleException(object(ClassNotFoundError))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).